# Adding file name and safe file name to DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, openfiledialog

This seems like this should be simple. I have a program that pulls in the file name and file path of in two separate columns when I use the OpenFileDialog. I am using a foreach statement that adds a row for each file selected in the OpenFileDialog (Note, I'm using multi-select in my ofd).

When I select one file, everything works great because there is only 1 file name (string) in the array. When I select 2 files though, four lines are added to my DataGridView. I know I shouldn't be using 2 `foreach` statements with the `dataGridView1.Rows.Add` function.

Is there a simple way to add the array into the column without using the `Add` portion of the `dataGridView1.Rows.Add`? I want to add a string into each cell in the third column (from my OpenFileDialog array), but without it adding a row each time.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofd.Filter = "*.SFP, *.SFL|*.sfp; *.sfl";
            ofd.Multiselect = true;


        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] selectedFiles = ofd.SafeFileNames;
            string[] filePaths = ofd.FileNames;

            foreach (string selectedFile in selectedFiles)
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selectedFile, "", filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I have also tried the following and received the results in the screenshot below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.Filter = "*.SFP, *.SFL|*.sfp; *.sfl";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;


        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] selectedFiles = ofd.SafeFileNames;
            string[] filePaths = ofd.FileNames;

            foreach (string selectedFile in selectedFiles)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selectedFile);
            }
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", "", filePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I really think this is something simple. New programmer here. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string[] selectedFiles = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            string[] filePaths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < openFileDialog1.FileNames.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selectedFiles[i], filePaths[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You may want to explain your code. That will help SO users a lot.